# Use jQuery to attribute selector to select all IDs and run a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get all the IDs that start with blblblb_ and run a separate JS function that I made. Here is what I have, it is only getting the first ID:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var test = $('div[id^="blblblb_"]').attr('id');
  foo(test);
});
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that [attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) gives you the id of the first element in collection and you're only calling `foo` once anyway.

Use [each](http://api.jquery.com/each/) to execute a function for all elements of a jquery collection :

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    $('div[id^="blblblb_"]').each(function(){
        foo(this.id);
    });
});
```

---

Based on your comment, if you have a growing collection of objects having this kind of id and wanting to be sure foo is only called once for each id, you might do this :

```
var done = {};
$(window).scroll(function() {
    $('div[id^="blblblb_"]').each(function(){
         if (!done[id]) {
             foo(this.id);
             done[id] = 1;
         }
    });
});
```

But I'm doubtful about the use case...

Comment: That works but how do I omit id's that i already have? I guess that each time I start scrolling it starts again?

Comment: I'm not sure I get what you mean with id you already have. Do you mean the list of objects having this kind of id change and you want to execute foo only once for each id ?

Comment: I edited but is that really what you want ? I can't imagine a situation where you'd need this.

Comment: Hey thanks! I can use an array to see if the same id is in or not. Btw.. Im using this for tracking